# How to find out how many hours a disk has been mounted?

Tags: hard-drive, mount

My box has an uptime of 400 days, but I saw one disk smart reported online hours of 270 hours. I suspect someone hot swapped that disk. How to find out?

Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       276

Comment: A confusing question, especially its body against the title. First of all, *volumes* (FS instances, also called *partitions*) are mounted, not “disks”. Secondly, disk (containing the volume) could be physically offline whereas the OS may deem the volume mounted.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the last mount time with `tune2fs`(for ext* filesystems). Example on Debian 7:

```
root@wheezy:~# tune2fs -l /dev/sda1
tune2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          4b7e1b6a-a6ff-47a8-be65-d4c32c05dcf5
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              1893120
Block count:              7572480
Reserved block count:     378624
Free blocks:              7127797
Free inodes:              1843283
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      1022
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8160
Inode blocks per group:   510
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Wed Oct 12 10:04:11 2016
Last mount time:          Mon Jan 30 09:53:03 2017
Last write time:          Mon Jan 30 09:53:03 2017
Mount count:              5
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Wed Oct 12 10:04:11 2016
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          3503 MB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      01c6a9d1-d5fe-41d7-9fa7-8a5a96c5dbed
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

For `nfs` you can view the `age` parameter in `/proc/self/mountstats` - it's in seconds.

Comment: That would of course only apply to read/write mounts of an ext* file system.